# Where does auth0 lock config go?

Tags: reactjs, auth0

Im not sure where to put the auth0 lock config. I tried putting it in the Auth file but I could not get it to work. Their documentation is unclear to me as to where I should put it in my project. I am following this guide here: 
https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v11

I am also using Reactjs.

Answer (score -1):

Are you following the React SPA quickstart? It's located on our Docs site at https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react

Comment: When I go the the embed lock link it returns a 404: https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-react-samples/tree/embedded-login/01-Embedded-Login

Comment: Is there a more simple way to edit the lock component style within the react set up through the quickstart ? Is there somewhere I can just pass the options too?

Comment: Because I have everything working just need to style the lock component.

Comment: Sorry I missed this - didn't get any notification you had replied.

So that link works fine for me? https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-react-samples/tree/embedded-login/01-Embedded-Login

We have a number of customization options for Lockv11 - they're listed here (https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v11/ui-customization) and we're continually adding more.